# Package vs Library

Tags: cmake, package, libraries, difference

I've just started working with CMake and I noticed that they have both a `find_package` and a `find_library`. And this confuses me. Can somebody explain the difference between a package and a library in the world of programming? Or, in the world of CMake?

Appreciate it, guys!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Imagine you want to use zlib in your project, you need to find the header file `zlib.h`, and the library `libz.so` (on Linux). You can use the low-level cmake commands `find_path` and `find_library` to find them, or you can use `find_package(ZLIB)`. The later command will try to find out all what is necessary to use zlib. It can be extra macro definitions, or dependencies.

**Update, more detail about `find_package`**: when the CMake command `find_package(SomeThing)` is called, [as in the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), there are two possible modes that cmake can run:

- the module mode (that searches for a file `FindSomeThing.cmake`)
- or the config mode (that searches for a file named `SomeThingConfig.cmake`)

For ZLIB, there is a module named `FindZLIB`, shipped with CMake itself (on my Linux machine that is the file `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake`). That module is a CMake script that uses the CMake API to search for ZLIB files in default locations, or ask the user for the location if it cannot be found automatically.

Comment: How is ZLIB defined though? Who wrote the commands necessary to find out what is necessary to use zlib?

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: I have amended by answer.